# List only certain files in a folder

Tags: bash, list

I have this directory structure.  How to list only files in all F40 sub sub folders in bash? Thanks

[image]

Comment: I think you could use `grep` here and condition it on the files' paths.

Comment: Do you mean `ls DIR/*/*/*/F40` ?

Comment: Or with `bash` 4+, you can use `shopt -s globstar; ls **/F40`

Answer (score 3):

The `find` command, combined with `ls`, can do it. For instance like this:

```sh
find DIR -type d -name F40 -exec ls {} \;
```

As the GNU `find` man page says, the `find` command is used for file search in a directory hierarchy.

In this case `find` searches the `DIR` folder for folders (`-type d`) explicitly named `F40`, and then it executes the `ls` (*list directory*) command to show what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can your xargs with find command

```
find DIR -type d -name F40 | xargs ls
```